# How to clear/refresh figure in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, reliability

I'm trying to design a user interface for an app. The app will be using `reliability` and `fitter` to show the user some graphs.

### Problems

Using `reliability` is difficult to show the graph on `tkinter` without having a mini figure popping out constantly as `reliability` use `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Next, the main problem, when plotting the graph in `tkinter`. I want it to change to another graph when I clicked on the button. But what I tried so far is pointless so far, the graph will be all stacked up. I have tried `.get_tk_widget.delete()` and methods mention in other posts but it won't remove the graph that is on `tkinter`. `plt.clf()` on remove the figure that pops up but not on the ones in `tkinter`.

[Graph stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyaiL.png)

#### Here is what I have done

The below code is a simple version of what I trying to design. If anyone is interested, the full code is [here](https://github.com/Isaac-98/POFapp/blob/main/The%20main%20application).

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from reliability.Fitters import Fit_Weibull_3P
from reliability.Probability_plotting import plot_points

main_data= pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\Documents\All data.xlsx')
df= pd.read_excel(main_data, '124 deg' , names= ['RSR 100', 'BS'])
df1 = pd.read_excel(main_data, '154 deg', names= ['RSR 100', 'BS'])
df.index=np.arange(1,len(df['BS'])+1)
df1.index=np.arange(1,len(df1['BS'])+1)
data1= abs(df.loc[:, 'BS'].to_numpy())
data2= abs(df1.loc[:, 'BS'].to_numpy())

def plot_graph(): 
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
    fit_distributions = Fit_Weibull_3P(failures= data1, show_probability_plot= False, print_results= False)
    plt1 = fig.add_subplot(111) #subplot here is to make the pyplot to be embed on tkinter.
    fit_distributions.distribution.CDF(label='Fitted Distribution', color='Steelblue')
    plot_points(failures=data1, func='CDF', label='Failure data', color='red', alpha= 0.7)
    plt.legend() 
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)  
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

def plot_next_graph():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
    fit_distributions = Fit_Weibull_3P(failures= data2, show_probability_plot= False, print_results= False)
    plt1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    fit_distributions.distribution.CDF(label='Fitted Distribution', color='Steelblue')
    plot_points(failures=data2, func='CDF', label='Failure data', color='red', alpha= 0.7)
    plt.legend()
    plt.close()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)  
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Plotting in Tkinter')
window.geometry("500x500")
plot_button1 = ttk.Button(master = window, command = plot_graph, width = 15, text = "Plot 124 deg")
plot_button1.pack()
plot_button2 = ttk.Button(master = window, command = plot_next_graph, width = 15, text = "Plot 154 deg")
plot_button2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I am still a beginner in `Python` and `tkinter`, would appreciate if anyone would spend their time to help and guide me. Thank you.

Comment: I believe your repository is private ...

Comment: Updated it. sorry about that.